# Linear Regression with positive coefficients in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to find a way to fit a linear regression model with positive coefficients.

The only way I found is [sklearn's Lasso model](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html), which has a `positive=True` argument, but doesn't recommend using with `alpha=0` (means no other constraints on the weights).

Do you know of another model/method/way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

IIUC, this is a problem which can be solved by the [`scipy.optimize.nnls`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html), which can do non-negative least squares.

> Solve argmin_x || Ax - b ||_2 for x>=0.

In your case, *b* is the *y*, *A* is the *X*, and *x* is the *β* (coefficients), but, otherwise, it's the same, no?

Answer (score 4):

Many functions can keep linear regression model with positive coefficients.

1. [scipy.optimize.nnls](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html) can solve above problem.
2. scikit-learn [LinearRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) can set the parameter `positive=True` to solve this. And, the sklearn also uses the `scipy.optimize.nnls`. Interestingly, you can learn how to write **multiple targets outputs** in source code.
3. Additionally, if you want to solve linear least squares with bounds on the variables. You can see [lsq_linear](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html#scipy.optimize.lsq_linear)
   .

Answer (score 1):

As of version 0.24, scikit-learn `LinearRegression` includes a similar argument `positive`, which does exactly that; from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html):

> **positive : *bool, default=False***
>
> When set to `True`, forces the coefficients to be positive. This option is only supported for dense arrays.
>
> *New in version 0.24.*